# Onedrive API list files shared with external users

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I am using PowerShell and the OneDrive APIs to accomplish this.  I can get all of the folders/files/etc, but I am having a hard time finding where I can list all of the users a certain file has been shared with.  My scope already contains wl.skydrive_contacts and I have a listing of all folders/files using the APIs already.  Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your code, and the error that you get when you run it?

Comment: I'm using this to get my drive root and can pick folders/files out by calling the different folder IDs.  The part that is puzzling me is getting permissions for these shared files.  When I run this, I can see that $_.shared_with shows Access=Shared.  
    
    $Root = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$ApiUri/me/skydrive?access_token=$AccessToken"

Comment: Also, the error that I get when running invoke-restmethod -Method GET -URI "$APIURI/$FileID/Permissions?access_token=$accesstoken is that the URL contains the path Permissions which is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OneDrive Rest API to list all shared items.

Before that, you need register an application to get proper access to your OneDrive according to https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm

Then you can make use the code below.

```
$ClientId = "<Your application client id>" # your application clientid 
$SecrectKey = "<Your application key>" # the secrect key for your application 
$RedirectURI = "<Your web app redirect url>" # the re-direct url of your application 

Function List-SharedItem 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$ClientId, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$SecrectKey, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$RedirectURI 
    ) 

    # import the utils module 
    Import-Module ".\OneDriveAuthentication.psm1" 

    # get token 
    $Token = New-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken -ClientId $ClientId -RedirectURI $RedirectURI -SecrectKey $SecrectKey 

    # you can store the token somewhere for the later usage, however the token will expired 
    # if the token is expired, please call Update-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken to update token 
    # e.g. 
    # $RefreshedToken = Update-AccessTokenAndRefreshToken -ClientId $ClientId -RedirectURI $RedirectURI -RefreshToken $Token.RefreshToken -SecrectKey $SecrectKey 

    # construct authentication header 
    $Header = Get-AuthenticateHeader -AccessToken $Token.AccessToken 

    # api root 
    $ApiRootUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0" 

    # call api 
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Header -Method GET -Uri "$ApiRootUrl/drive/shared" 

    RETURN $Response.value 
} 

# call method to do job 
$Results = List-SharedItem -ClientId $ClientId -SecrectKey $SecrectKey -RedirectURI $RedirectURI 

# print results 
$Results | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "ID: $($_.id)" 
    Write-Host "Name: $($_.name)" 
    Write-Host "ParentReference: $($_.parentReference)" 
    Write-Host "Size: $($_.size)" 
    Write-Host "WebURL: $($_.webUrl)" 
    Write-Host 
}
```

For complete instructions, you can see the sample in https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-use-OneDrive-Rest-5b31cf78